# Working with Excel Dates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am experiencing a problem when attempting to read a date from an excel sheet. (The date column is formatted the same as the short date format of the computer its opened on). I populate the dates from the excel sheet into a datagrid with success, but when I attempt to parse the date (To format it appropriately), I get a error saying the string wasn't a valid DateTime value. The computer's short date format is dd/MM/yyyy. This is the code I use to try parsing the date. The following code is an example of where the process fails.

`Dim dateParsed AS DateTime = DateTime.Parse("14/01/2013").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Is there some way to programatically get the system's short date format and use ParseExact instead or any suggestions?

Comment: These links can help you                                                  [1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=VS.90%29.aspx            [2]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @DominicKexel I have tested it and effectively OPTION STRICT is OFF allows the proposed configuration.

Comment: A note: you say so that you may "format it appropriately". I might suggest the most appropriate way to format a date is using the Culture-Specific formats of the current user. Forcing "yyyy-MM-dd" on the user might not be the best option. (depending on what you're planning to do with the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to parse exact, using the current cultures short-date format?

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "d", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Additionally, if you actually need to see the ShortDate format for yourself get it through the CurrentCulture.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this piece of coding

```
      Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("1/14/2013").ToString

      Dim f As String = Format(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Why are you Parsing a DateTime object called "str"? it's already a DateTime.